# Solve the error : could not convert string to float: '0.1222000000*10e1'

Tags: python

Consider:

```
expo2 = ['0.1222000000*10E1', '0.9310000000*10E-1', '0.2580000000*10E1', '0.2580000000*10E1', '0.2580000000*10E1', '0.8850000000*10E-1', '0.8850000000*10E-1', '0.8850000000*10E-1', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.1222000000*10E1', '0.9310000000*10E-1', '0.2580000000*10E1', '0.2580000000*10E1', '0.2580000000*10E1', '0.8850000000*10E-1', '0.8850000000*10E-1', '0.8850000000*10E-1', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10E0', '0.8850000000*10E0']
```

I have a list of numbers. I would like to use them, so I tried to use the float commands but, when I wrote:

```
print(float(expo2[0]))
```

I got this error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.1222000000*10e1'
```

How can I convert those numbers to floats?

Comment: Remove `*10` from the strings and then try your conversion

Comment: how did you get that list of strings

Comment: That does not work @Magali

Comment: I tried, and now i can use the number in a mathematic function ...

Comment: What number you you expect to get from `0.1222000000*10e1`? If you run that through `eval()`, it produces 12.22 which is correct because `10e1` is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is actually the correct formula:

```
expo2 = ['0.1222000000*10e1', '0.9310000000*10e-1', '0.2580000000*10e1', '0.2580000000*10e1', '0.2580000000*10e1', '0.8850000000*10e-1', '0.8850000000*10e-1', '0.8850000000*10e-1', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.1222000000*10e1', '0.9310000000*10e-1', '0.2580000000*10e1', '0.2580000000*10e1', '0.2580000000*10e1', '0.8850000000*10e-1', '0.8850000000*10e-1', '0.8850000000*10e-1', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0', '0.8850000000*10e0']


floats = []
for f in expo2:
    try:
        a, e = f.split("*")
        floats.append(float(a) * float(e))
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Not a float")
print(floats)
```

```
[12.22, 0.931, 25.8, 25.8, 25.8, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 12.22, 0.931, 25.8, 25.8, 25.8, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85]
```

You can verify by using *eval*:

```
print(all(a == eval(b) for a,b in zip(floats, expo2)))
True
```

`10e-1` is 1 `10e1` is 100:

```
In [25]: 10e-1
Out[25]: 1.0
In [26]: 10e-2
Out[26]: 0.1
In [27]: 10e-3
Out[27]: 0.01
In [28]: 10e1 # 10 * 10^1 -> 10 * 10
Out[28]: 100.0
In [29]: 10e2 # 10 * 10^2 -> 10 * 10 * 10
Out[29]: 1000.0
In [30]: 10e3 # 10 * 10^3 -> 10 * 10 * 10 * 10
Out[30]: 10000.0
```

A table from [this site](http://albert-cordova.com/_science/exponent.html) using 1.0 as the coefficient:

```
1.0 is Coefficient

10 is BASE

N is EXPONENT

1.0*10E-24= 0.000,000,000,000,000,000,000,001 or Yocto

1.0*10E-21= 0.000,000,000,000,000,000,001 or Zepto

1.0*10E-18= 0.000,000,000,000,000,001 or 1 Quintillionth, alto

1.0*10E-15= 0.000,000,000,000,001 or 1 quadrillionth, femto

1.0*10E-12= 0.000,000,000,001 or 1 Trillionth, Pico

1.0*10E-11= 0.000,000,000,01

1.0*10E-10= 0.000,000,000,1

1.0*10E-09= 0.000,000,001 or 1 billionth, nano

1.0*10E-08= 0.000,000,01

1.0*10E-07= 0.000,000,1

1.0*10E-06= 0.000,001 or 1 Millionth, micro

1.0*10E-05= 0.000,01

1.0*10E-04= 0.000,1

1.0*10E-03= 0.001 or 1 thousandth, milli

1.0*10E-02= 0.01 or centi

1.0*10E-01= 0.1 or deci

1.0*10E00= 1 or Units or (V,I,R,P,)(Meter,Liter,Gram,)(Seconds)ƒ(Herz Cycles)

1.0*10E01= 10 or Deka

1.0*10E02= 100 or Hecto

1.0*10E03= 1,000 or Kilo

1.0*10E04= 10,000 or (10K)

1.0*10E05= 100,000 or (100K)

1.0*10E06= 1,000,000 or Mega

1.0*10E07= 10,000,000 or (10M)

1.0*10E08= 100,000,000 or (100M)

1.0*10E09= 1,000,000,000 or Giga

1.0*10E12= 100,000 000,000 or Tera

1.0*10E15= 100,000,000,000,000 or Peta

1.0*10E18= 100,000,000,000,000,000 or Exa

1.0*10E21= 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 or Zetta

1.0*10E24= 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 or Yotta
```

If you have a mixture:

```
expo2 = ['0.1222000000*10e2', "1.0", "4r", "2.123e4", '0.9310000000*10e-1', '0.2580000000*10e1',"foo"]

floats = []

for f in expo2:
    try:
        a, e = f.split("*")
        floats.append(float(a) * float(e))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            floats.append(float(f))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
```

Output:

```
could not convert string to float: '4r'
could not convert string to float: 'foo'
[122.2, 1.0, 21230.0, 0.931, 25.8]
```

Comment: After your comment I didn't expect you would `print('Not a float')` ! Ah ah what a shame ;-)

Comment: @GiovanniLombardo, I am going to add a more general approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

The number's format in the list does not match the one used by Python's float() function. You should working on your strings to actually obtains floating point numbers by them. A solution to your question might be splitting the strings to represent two floating point numbers and then multiply them together, like in the following snippet:

```
from sys import stderr

callback = lambda x: stderr.write('Invalid floating point number found:{0}'.format(x))

def convert(src, error_callback):
    ret = list()
    for item in src:
        index = item.find('*')
        if index == -1:
            error_callback(item)
            continue
        try: ret.append(float(item[:index]) * (float(item[index+1:])/10))
        except ValueError: error_callback(item)
    return ret
```

Now if you call:

```
expo2_floats = convert(expo2, callback)
```

You get:

```
[1.222, 0.09310000000000002, 2.58, 2.58, 2.58, 0.08850000000000001, 0.08850000000000001, 0.08850000000000001, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 1.222, 0.09310000000000002, 2.58, 2.58, 2.58, 0.08850000000000001, 0.08850000000000001, 0.08850000000000001, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885, 0.885]
```

Comment: Just because `*` was not in the string would not mean it was invalid

Comment: Good point! But in this case I assume that strings are in that specific format ... as required. With a little bit of editing you could generalize the function to handle other formats too.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `'` marks. You, by wrapping numbers in these marks, are making them strings.
Float doesn't work for strings!

Do this:

```
 expo2 = [2125*10e1, ...]
 print expo2[0]
```

It will work.